# How to Convert http links to html link tags using vim

Tags: regex, vim

i have a text file like that

```
link1
http://linkdemo1.com/path/

link2
http://linkdemo2.com/path/

link3
http://linkdemo3.com/path/
```

i want to replace it to be like that using vim

```
<a href="http://linkdemo1.com/path/">link1</a>
<a href="http://linkdemo2.com/path/">link2</a>
<a href="http://linkdemo3.com/path/">link3</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
/(\w+)\n(http(s)?:.*)/
```

and replace with `<a href="$2">$1</a>`

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/eF0rG0/1)

Answer (score 0):

This command would do the transformation for you:

```
:%s@\v^(\S+)\_s*(http://.*)@<a href="\2">\1</a>@
```

or with `:g` can do it as well:

```
:g/^http/norm! -ddi<a href="^[A">^R"^H</a>
```

note:

```
press ^[ by: ctrl-v <esc>
press ^R by: Ctrl-v Ctrl-r
press ^H by: ctrl-v ctrl-h
```